# Demonstration video for the appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, itunes

I uploaded my app to itunes connect and i waited a few days.. and then the app that i uploaded was denied.
1 of the reason was that i didnt had a demonstration video with my app in use?

> Furthermore, we began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use.
>
> The video must show the full process of functionality from signing in to the different sections off the application.
>
> You can provide a link to a demo video of your app in iTunes Connect. Go to "Manage Your Applications," select your app, click "Edit Information," then scroll to the "Review Notes" section and add the demonstration video access details."

What do i need to do?
Use a screen capture software and film my app in use in the simulator?
Upload to youtube and share the link in the review notes of the app?
A simple demonstration? or a expanded demonstration?

Anny help wouldnt be helpfull, ty!.

Comment: Oh My God! I haven't seen such thing before...

Comment: If they will ask now demonstration video for each of my app it will be gg

Comment: hmm, i dont know.. its my first time deploying a app into the appstore..

Comment: Is not it obvious how to use your app?

Comment: It is.. you just need to login to it(for our customers) and the UI shows it self...

Comment: Do you provide test user login and pwd in `Review Notes`?

Comment: No, not yet i also wrote in the review notes : "This app only works when you have a local server installed. We have no way of providing a demo account to you easily. How can we proceed in this matter?"

Comment: and they did not respond to that question.

Comment: And they respond to your question - video =)

Comment: Simulator screen capture videos have a high chance of rejection the second time. See below for our answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about policy compliance with a 3rd party service, not about programming as defined by the [help]. Questions about compliance with Apple products or services should be directed to Apple support, instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apple tends to ask for a video of the app in use if it's not clear how the app operates. Common causes are that the app is not written in English (so the reviewers can't read the app instructions), is tied to a site that requires login, or makes use of specific hardware. In these cases, the app reviewers can't easily verify correct operation of the app and would like a video showing common use so they can repeat the steps and verify the app.

My understanding is that a YouTube video will suffice.

There are some options (including free or trial software) for recording your app here:

http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=670

Good luck!
Mike

Comment: Simulator screen capture videos have a high chance of rejection the second time. See below for our answer.

Comment: The language of the app should not make a difference. I submitted apps without english localization and they were accepted.

Comment: @who9vy yes it matters. Highly.

Comment: TRY THIS ONE ;) https://www.kapwing.com/

Answer (score 8):

Yes it has to be a video on iOS device. They rejected the app again saying :

Second time:
"Specifically, it may be appropriate to provide us with a demo video that displays the full functionality of the app while displaying a proper iOS device."

First time:
"We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use."

It looks like some Apple testers are not provided an iPhone with working data plan. So when an app requires to have an iOS device for field test (e.g. an app used for finding places to eat in 1/4 mile radius, outdoor activity app - running routes, biking trails, etc.), the tester has no way of knowing whether the app works or not, unless he/she sees the video. The other reason may be they just don't have time or don't want to do field test.

Comment: how to posible demo app video include camera function capture image at time function not capture only black screen display . my application reject for demonstration your application metadata reject error how to solve this one task any other guys please let me know .,,,,wait for your answer  i think you all guys understand my language

Answer (score 7):

I submitted my first app that required a device and one can't test it without it - it also got rejected the first time. Here is what you need to to:

1. Make a video that shows your apps functionality starting from pressing the app icon
2. Slowly go through the screens so one can follow. It is also helpful to add some explanatory text
3. The video does not have to be professional, but it needs to show all the main functionality
4. You may use all sorts of recording techniques, but the easiest I find just to use another iPhone. You may spend as much time as you like making the video professional.
5. Make a note for the reviewer and add the link to youtube so that Apple can easily get to it

That should do it.

Comment: Hi, you say that the app works with a specific device (maybe using wifi or bluetooth?). I'm in the same situation but don't know if a video can be enought for the review process or if they need also the device used to communicate with the app.

Comment: There is never aguarantee - in my case it would be too much effort to get the equipment and test it anyway. Apple accepted my app with the demo video...

Comment: Where do I need to upload demo video? I tried uploading .mp4 and .mov files on "iTunes Connect : Resolution Center"

Comment: just upload wherever and give them the link - that's what I have done

Comment: which one place upload demo video let me know i don't know please all guys

Answer (score 2):

While a video captured with simulator on the Mac looks neat and is somewhat more easy to be created, it would be more "safe" to record one on your physical device.

Sometimes reviewers want to see if your app really runs well on the device, not just on the simulator. They may request another video shots and it will delay review process a bit longer.

Comment: Yes it has to be a video on iOS device. They rejected the app again saying :

Answer (score 0):

mhm
that's may be a new rule...
i've uploaded a new app just a week ago (with no video help),
and apple accepted it with no video-request...

or probably "mike Bobbit" is right, your app is not too much clear in what it should do, how it works...

any way, i was thinking to create a video for the web page of my app, and i wiil probably use a digital camera, but a good way could be to use a "capture screen" app on my mac, and using the xCode iPhone simulator...

there are many software to capture screen, in past i used "[snapz](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/)"
but there are many other...

Comment: No. Simulator screen capture videos have a high chance of rejection the second time. See below for our answer.

Comment: how to possible  camera capture image ae time video creation for demonstration for application how to possible