# Create ios app demo video

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the best way to record a video for ios application ? I have a business application and now i want to create a some demo video for our clients, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you searched on Stackoverflow at all? Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485201/demonstration-video-for-the-appstore).

Comment: @taffarel, if my answer helped you, can you please accept it and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in simulator, Apple's quicktime player has an option to record screen activities. Try with that. In an empty background or so, start your simulator and run the quicktime player.In order to run, go to file menu and start the new screen recording option. It has an option to select only a portion of the screen. There were many other tools. Check [this link.](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/10-screen-recording-tools-for-mac/) I have used Snapz Pro X to record the video of iOS apps in simulator. If you want to do it in device, [try this.](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57455241-285/you-can-now-record-your-ios-devices-screen-with-display-recorder/)

To do it programmatically, [try this](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673).

In that code, change

```
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
```

to

```
[[self.layer presentatationLayer] renderInContext:context];
```

Comment: This is an easier and better solution
http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/create-video-for-your-app-on-app-store-3532435/

Comment: how to posible  objective c application include camera capture function at time create demo video for application ,how to create this the function please let me know ,